# ${p_n}$ is such that $S_n = {1\over p_1}+{1\over p_2}+\cdots+{1\over p_n}$ converges. Prove $\sigma_n = \left(1+{1\over p_1}\right)\cdots$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Let $\{p_n\}$ denote a sequence such that:
>   $$
> S_n = {1\over p_1} + {1\over p_2} + \cdots + {1\over p_n}
> $$
>   converges.
>   Prove that:
>   $$
> \sigma_n = \left(1+{1\over p_1}\right)\left(1+{1\over p_2}\right)\cdots\left(1+{1\over p_n}\right)
> $$
>   converges, where $n, p_n \in \Bbb N$.

Consider each bracket from $\sigma_n$. By ${1\over p_n} > 0$:
$$
\forall k \in \Bbb N: \left(1+{1\over p_k}\right) > 1
$$
So $\sigma_n$ must be monotonically increasing by:
$$
{\sigma_{n+1} \over \sigma_n} = \left(1+{1\over p_{n+1}}\right) > 1
$$

To show a monotonic sequence is convergent it's sufficient to show that it's bounded above. Lets try to find the bound.
Recall:
$$
\ln(1+x) \le x \iff (1+x) \le e^x \tag1
$$
So by $(1)$ we have:
$$
\sigma_n \le e^{S_n}
$$
But $S_n$ is convergent! And thus:
$$
\sigma_n \le e^L
$$
where:
$$
L = \lim_{n\to\infty}S_n
$$
Which by monotone convergence theorem proves $\sigma_n$ is convergent.

I'm kindly asking to verify my proof and point to the mistakes in case of any. Thank you!

Comment: If $p_n >0$, $\sigma_n$ is easily proved to be increasing and the inequality $\sigma_n \leq e^{S_n} \leq e^L$ is easy as well. Some passages are very strange (why do you need $1/p_n \rightarrow 0$? What is your digression about the harmonic series?) but the crux seems quite correct.

Comment: @Mindlack please notice a part in the question section saying $n, p_n \in \Bbb N$

Comment: @Mindlack as far as the other notices, I agree with you, I will update the post

Comment: Right, thank you. I edited.

Comment: This is correct now. You can actually even write that each factor $(1+1/p_n)$ is lower than $e^{1/p_n}$, shortening the argument.

Comment: @Mindlack thank you! I've been able to eliminate the $\ln$ part.

Comment: Nicely done!...